# Caesar cipher brute force into one function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def caesar_decrypt(s,n):
    s1=""
    m = n % 26 if n > 26 else n
    for c in s:
        if c.isalpha():
          x = ord(c) - m
          if c.islower():
             c = chr(x + 26) if x < ord('a') else chr(x)
          elif c.isupper():
             c = chr(x + 26) if x < ord('A') else chr(x)
        s1 += c
    return s1

def brute_force_decrypt(ciphertext):
    for i in range(1,27):
        d=caesar_decrypt(ciphertext,i)
        print (i,d)
brute_force_decrypt(open('text.txt').read())
```

So, my code does a fine job, but I want the code to be put into one function called  brute_force_decrypt(ciphertext). I'm not sure on how to combine the two function I have. I need some help.

Comment: The real trick is to determine in the code when the correct decryption has been found.

Answer (score 2):

Don't, a function is best if it does one thing and is well named.

Instead create another function that calls each of these functions.

The less in a function the easier to understand and the less chance of an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the code of `caesar_decrypt(s,n)` in `brute_force_decrypt(ciphertext)`

```
def brute_force_decrypt(ciphertext):
    for n in range(1,27):
        s1=""
        m = n % 26 if n > 26 else n
        for c in ciphertext:
            if c.isalpha():
              x = ord(c) - m
              if c.islower():
                 c = chr(x + 26) if x < ord('a') else chr(x)
              elif c.isupper():
                 c = chr(x + 26) if x < ord('A') else chr(x)
            s1 += c
        d = s1
        print (n,d)
brute_force_decrypt(open('text.txt').read())
```

(Note the change in variable `i` to `n`)

Comment: Then I get an Error. NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: @New_to_python Notice it is harder to see what is happening now. Also better descriptive variable names make it easier to reason what is happening.

Comment: @New_to_python Edited the code. No more `s`. Replaced with `ciphertext`

Comment: @zaph , I agree, but it doesn't seem like a lot of code.

Comment: @nikpod Thank you. Just what I need.

Comment: According to "Uncle Bob" Martin a function is best with 5 to 7 lines of code. This conflates two things (encryption and  brute-force) that might well be usable separately. "non mi importa".

Comment: To reduce the number of lines, you can replace line numbers 5 to 13 in the above code to: `d=''.join([((chr(ord(c) - m + 26) if (ord(c) - m) < (ord('a') if c.islower() else ord('A')) else chr(ord(c) - m)) if c.isalpha() else c) for c in "asd2"])`
Yes, this is further unreadable but solves the 5 to 7 lines of code suggestion :D

Comment: Writing good understandable code is not about reducing the number of lines of code. The 5-7 lines is about creating small functions that perform one thing in a very human understandable manor. Further, code is made more understandable by well named descriptive variables, not single letter and short names such as `n, s1, m, c, x, d` which do not convey meaning of usage. Take a look at [Clean Code, Episode 1](https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-1/show).